# Responsive Logo Positioning with Logo with menus

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I am learning responsive designs.now i am creating a responsive website..it has name logo and left and right there is two horizontal lines.logo should be in top center. under the logo i have to place menus.In responsive design view it should maintain the center place

Comment: so what's the problem? you want us to design it for you?

Comment: You need to provide some code demonstrating your issue.

Comment: [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is way to big to answer here but media queries is what you'll want. Watch this short You Tube video and you will get the basics down pretty quick

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fA1NW-T1QXc

Html in head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Html in body    `<div id="container"><div id="header">Logo</div></div>`

CSS `#container{width: 1000px; height: 500px;}`
`#header{width: 1000px; height: 100px; text-align: center;}`
`@media only screen and (max-width: 999px){#container{width:100%;}#header{width: 100%;background-color: blue;}}`

This is just an example, at 999px the header will turn blue and will size to your screen as long as your screen width is below 999px.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.